# Asking user input to copy sheets in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy sheets from a particular workbook in VBA to my Active Workbook and do a lot of calculations using it. Now the problem is that the target sheet name always keeps on changing and I always get an error.

```
Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
filter = "Text files (*.xls*),*.xls*"
Caption = "Please Select the Target file"
Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , Caption)

If Ret = False Then Exit Sub
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Ret)
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
wb.Worksheets("**This Keeeps on Changing**").Move After:=targetWorkbook.Sheets(targetWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
```

Can I select or Input the name in a MsgBox or something similar so that I dont get an error. Please help.

Comment: Set the worksheet being copied to a variable, now you have a reference to it and can continue your code using the variable as well as change the name at the same time.  [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7692456/2521004) by Tim Williams

Comment: And if you wanted to go down the road you are suggestion, `mySheet = inputbox(...` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub ertdfgcvb()
Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Filter = "Text files (*.xls*),*.xls*"
Caption = "Please Select the Target file"
Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filter, , Caption)

If Ret = False Then Exit Sub
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Ret, False) 'why set it on application level when it's an optional argument?

shname = InputBox("What worksheet are you looking for?", "Changing sheet names are for losers")
For Each Worksheet In wb
    If LCase(Worksheet.Name) Like "*" & LCase(shname) & "*" Then                              'it might be changing but it probably has a fixed part, right? 'note: you can use wildcards and string conversion rules
        Worksheet.Move After:=targetWorkbook.Sheets(targetWorkbook.Sheets.Count) 'do whatever it did before
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Got it. Will try to use this. Its just  the data  I use of a  file not updated by me and have seen sheet names changing, so just wanted to make it general. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Filter = "Text files (*.xls*),*.xls*"
Caption = "Please Select the Target file"
Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filter, , Caption)

If Ret = False Then Exit Sub
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Ret, False) 'why set it on application level when it's an optional argument?

For Each Worksheet In wb
    If LCase(Worksheet.Name) Like "*changing*" Then                              'it might be changing but it probably has a fixed part, right? 'note: you can use wildcards and string conversion rules
        Worksheet.Move After:=targetWorkbook.Sheets(targetWorkbook.Sheets.Count) 'do whatever it did before
    End If
Next
```

Comment: inb4 methods, not rules