# Trying to copy a worksheet to an existing workbook in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy data from a worksheet, opened from a CSV file, as a new worksheet in an existing Excel template.  I have tried copying to an existing, empty worksheet as well as copying the source worksheet in as a new sheet in the target workbook.  All of these methods have thrown a variety of errors.  The only method that actually allowed the code to complete was a copy-paste-special command.  However, it resulted in cells being filled with binary as opposed to values and many cells were filled with a grayed out appearance.

Below is the code I have been trying to get working:

```
'=================================================
'Add Data
'=================================================
Dim AppExcell As Object
Dim wb As Object
Dim xFile As String
Dim main As Workbook

Set AppExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
AppExcel.Visible = False

Set wb = AppExcel.Workbooks.Add("C:\Fridge_Automation\Lab Report.xltm")
Set main = ActiveWorkbook

xFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("All CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Select CSV File")

Set src = Workbooks.Open(xFile)

src.Worksheets(1).Copy Before:=wb.Worksheets("11Mic Avg - Raw Data")
wb.Worksheets(2).Name = "Raw Data"
src.Close
```

I am running this code in Excel 2013 by clicking a button I have added to a worksheet.

Comment: Are you running this code from **Excel** ?

Comment: I have a button in an Excel sheet that then runs this code

Comment: Do you have code for your `GetOpenFilename` Function ?

Comment: I'm under the impression that function is a method of application, which is a standard feature of Excel: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834966.aspx

Comment: depends on what version of Excle you are running ?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2013

Comment: OK, so what is the source workbook ? is it the one you select with the `GetOpenFilename` ?

Comment: The source is a csv file that is opened as a new workbook with `GetOpenFilename`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code worked for me, run from within a workbook.  `***` flags things I changed.

```
Option Explicit             ' *** Always use this in every module
Option Base 0

Public Sub GrabSheet()

    'Dim AppExcel As Object ' *** don't need this
    'Dim wb As Object       ' ***
    Dim dest As Workbook    ' *** Instead of "wb"
    Dim xFile As String
    'Dim main As Workbook   ' ***

    'Set AppExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")   ' ***
    'AppExcel.Visible = False   ' ***
    'Application.Visible = False ' *** Uncomment if you really want to...

    Set dest = ActiveWorkbook   ' *** for testing - use Workbooks.Add("C:\Fridge_Automation\Lab Report.xltm") for your real code
    'Set main = ActiveWorkbook  ' *** don't need this

    xFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("All CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Select CSV File")

    Dim src As Workbook     ' *** Need to declare this because of "Option Explicit"
    Set src = Workbooks.Open(xFile)

    ' Per https://stackoverflow.com/q/7692274/2877364 , it is surprisingly
    ' difficult to get the new sheet after you copy.
    ' Make a unique name to refer to the sheet by.
    Dim sheetname As String                         ' ***
    sheetname = "S" & Format(Now, "yyyymmddhhmmss") ' ***
    src.Worksheets(1).Name = sheetname              ' ***

    src.Worksheets(1).Copy Before:=dest.Worksheets("11Mic Avg - Raw Data")  ' *** changed wb to dest
    'dest.Worksheets(2).Name = "Raw Data"           ' *** don't assume an index...
    dest.Worksheets(sheetname).Name = "Raw Data"    ' *** ... but use the name.
        ' *** NOTE: this fails if a "Raw Data" sheet already exists.
    src.Close SaveChanges:=False  ' *** Suppress the "save changes" prompt you otherwise get because of the `src...Name` assignment

End Sub
```

I used a custom sheet name to find the new sheet because of the issues listed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7692274/2877364).

You don't need to create an `AppExcel` object when you are running from within Excel.  Instead, you can just refer directly to `Application`.

Comment: When I add `Option Explicit` at the top of my function, it adds a divider to the code. In this case is it still best to have it at the top of the function or at after the functions code?

Comment: Option Explicit goes at the very top of the file, before any `Sub` in the file.  It requires you to use `Dim` statements for all your variables, which helps smoke out a lot of common errors.