# Macro for copy hidden sheet, rename and filter

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to copy and rename a hidden sheet?

I've created the macro as below

```
Sub Copyandrename()
'
' Copyandrename Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Template").Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
    Sheets("Template (2)").Name = "Issues and Key Takeaways"
    Rows("6:6").Select
    Range("C6").Activate
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Issues and Key Takeaways").AutoFilter.Sort. _
        SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Issues and Key Takeaways").AutoFilter.Sort. _
        SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C6"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Issues and Key Takeaways").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("D9").Select
End Sub
```

However once I hide the 'Template' tab, I'll get the following error.

Run-time error '91':

Object variable or With block variable not set

Any suggestions to fix the issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "wont work"? Do you get an error? if so, what error and on what line? Let me guess.. it's probably on one of the `.Select` or `.Activate` lines... you cannot select a hidden worksheet, but you can still write code that accesses it... you need to learn how to write code that doesnt use `.Select` and `.Activate`

Comment: Unhide the template, copy it, then hide it again.

Comment: @braX The error I received was Run-time error '91': Object variable or with Block variable not set

Comment: @TimWilliams - not possible, end user wants the template tab hidden after the running the macro

Comment: @TommyLi - that's what "then hide it again" means ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909585/copy-hidden-master-sheet-rename-it-and-place-it-at-end-of-workbook