# New Sheet keeps overwriting old name

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a worksheet and rename it based on a variable and that is working. The issue is that it changes the name of the template sheet in the process of copying. Any ideas how to fix it?

```
Sub AddAgent()

    Dim wsname As String
    Dim lRow As Long

    wsname = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Range("E5").Value

    Set ws = Sheets("Agent Template")

    ws.Copy After:=Sheets("Summary")

    Set wsNew = Sheets(Sheets("Summary").Index + 2)

    wsNew.Range("C4").Value = wsname
    wsNew.Name = wsname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, the `Copy()` function automatically sets the new worksheet as the `ActiveSheet`. So you wouldn't need to find it by index. You could simply access the properties of the `ActiveSheet` object:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    .Item("Agent Template").Copy After:=.Item("Summary")
End With

With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    .Name = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("E5").Value2
    .Range("C4").Value = .Name
End With
```

If my understanding is correct, then I'd favour this way, as you could lose control of indexing if users start moving sheets around.

Answer (score 1):

You're incrementing the `Index` too far

```
Set ws = Sheets("Agent Template")

ws.Copy After:=Sheets("Summary")

Set wsNew = Sheets(Sheets("Summary").Index + 1)
```

Note you can get unpredictable results if any sheets are hidden:
[Copy sheet and get resulting sheet object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692274/copy-sheet-and-get-resulting-sheet-object)