# Reference to new sheet after .Copy

Tags: excel, vba

How can I reference to the new sheet after its copied as a new workbook.

```
Dim MainWb As Workbook: Set MainWb = ThisWorkbook
Dim SheetToCopy As Worksheet: Set SheetToCopy = MainWb.ActiveSheet

SheetToCopy.Copy
```

Is there a way to define a name to it? Someting like

```
 Set CopiedSheet = SheetToCopy.Copy
```

Comment: Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692274/copy-sheet-and-get-resulting-sheet-object/7692456#7692456

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you copy a sheet it becomes the `ActiveSheet`, so you can reference that.

```
Dim MainWb As Workbook: Set MainWb = ThisWorkbook
Dim SheetToCopy As Worksheet: Set SheetToCopy = MainWb.ActiveSheet
Dim CopiedSheet As Worksheet

SheetToCopy.Copy 

Set CopiedSheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
```

Comment: When I use `.Copy` it creates a new workbook I want to reference to the sheet after its copied to a new workbook.

Comment: You need to reference the `activesheet` then. I've updated the answer.